issue when using injectable
when i use injectable package in my flutter application  to inject depandancies i am getting a error called in valid type in the gen6rated file but i checked everything and i am giving everything correctly this the line showing
gh.lazySingleton<_i8.AddEmployeeRepo>(() =>
    _i9.AddEmployeeRepoImpl(addEmployeeRemoteData: gh<InvalidType>()));   

i have checked everything but not  found  anything how can i solve this it is only showing that invalid type
